# Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1 - resource-rules has been deprecated

Tags: xcode6

```
CodeSign /Users/johannes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LoyaltyApp-elaicsznnwccdxdpbkrhdgrmkbgj/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Nerstranda.app
    cd /Users/johannes/Projects/Xcode/LoyaltyApp
    export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"

Signing Identity:     "iPhone Developer: Thomas Sorensen (Z48XZBVS3Q)"
Provisioning Profile: "iOSTeam Provisioning Profile: *"
                      (d8fc10a6-1a72-49c1-b0b6-00e9b46960bf)

    /usr/bin/codesign --force --sign 368251C7130CB04A93AAEB9C7392A94B27A7B9FF --resource-rules=/Users/johannes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LoyaltyApp-elaicsznnwccdxdpbkrhdgrmkbgj/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Nerstranda.app/ResourceRules.plist --entitlements /Users/johannes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LoyaltyApp-elaicsznnwccdxdpbkrhdgrmkbgj/Build/Intermediates/LoyaltyApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/Nerstranda.build/Nerstranda.app.xcent /Users/johannes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LoyaltyApp-elaicsznnwccdxdpbkrhdgrmkbgj/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Nerstranda.app

Warning: --resource-rules has been deprecated in Mac OS X >= 10.10!
368251C7130CB04A93AAEB9C7392A94B27A7B9FF: no identity found
Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1
```

I have no idea what this means, can anyone help?

EDIT: Seems like it works to run another target.. I have several targets for my project (if that info helps)

Comment: same issue, can't solve it yet.. The error is taking placeafter update to Xcode 6.1 in only one target..

Comment: @ShurupuS see my answer, I made it work

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I even contacted Apple about this because I have such short time on me until I have to deliver this product...

But then I figured it out, this helped for me ShurupuS.

Preferences > Accounts > View Details > Refresh button (left corner) > Close Xcode > Open Xcode > Product > Clean > Run

Comment: I had same issue this morning - I have also deleted all existing provisioning profiles at /Users/"MyUserName"/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning. Downloaded all new fresh provisioning profiles. Then it worked.

Comment: @Jhonannes . It worked for me on **xcode 6.0.1**. :)